# Mechanism for determining MSS during TCP 3-Way Handshake

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm troubleshooting a MTU/MSS issue that is causing fragmentation over a PPPoE service. Below is a packet dump of a TCP 3-Way Handshake from a different service (that is working as expected) that relates to my question.

[image]

I understand the way PMTUD works as this: by setting the Don't Fragment (DF) bit to 1 in the IP header, a router along the path to the destination that requires fragmentation of the packet sends an ICMP back to the host to adjust the MSS size accordingly. However, my understanding is that this will only happen when fragmentation occurs (packets greater than the path MTU). This suggests that PMTUD works during the data exchange phase, NOT when TCP 3-Way Handshake is negotiated (since these are small packets, 78 bytes in this case).

In the above packet capture the SYN packet sends a MSS=1460 (which is too large, due to the 8 byte overhead of PPPoE) and the SYN/ACK response from the server sends back the correct MSS=1452. What mechanism does TCP use to determine the MSS during this exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the server hasn't computed the MSS during this three-way handshake. For instance, if the system administrator has observed a lot of fragmentation, he can have set the MSS of the whole system to 1452 (with the command `ip tcp adjust-mss 1452`), so when you are doing the three-way handshake, the server only advertises its default MSS. Is it applicable to your case?

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably seeing here is the result of what's known as [MSS clamping](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html) where the network on which the server is attached to modifies the MSS in the outgoing SYN/ACK packets to signal to the sender to use a lower MSS. This is commonly done on networks that perform some form of tunnelling such as PPPoE on ADSL.